# CSS Problem : Center Text in a box with Image

Tags: css, image, button, center

Can anybody help? 
I'm struggling to get some CSS- Code to work.

I need three boxes; they need to look like in the picture

[image: this is what it should look like]

But when I run my code the text is always below the image.

Please can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ? :

https://codepen.io/arminx2/full/wYPxZe

```
</div><div style="margin-top: 16px; background: white; box-shadow: rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.25) -1px 1px 2px 1px; padding: 12px; height: 70px; border-radius: 2px; flex-direction: row; align-items: center; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; transition: all 1s linear 0s;"><img src="http://relationshiphero.com/images/sageTeal.png" style="height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right: 16px;"><div><div style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(5, 26, 90); margin-bottom: 2px;">16% better value</div><div style="color: rgb(0, 112, 232); font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">Sage - 60 minutes</div></div><div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: 8px; color: rgb(0, 112, 232);"><img src="/images/triangleRight.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;"></div></div><div style="margin-top: 16px; background: white; box-shadow: rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.25) -1px 1px 2px 1px; padding: 12px; height: 70px; border-radius: 2px; flex-direction: row; align-items: center; cursor: pointer; opacity: 1; transition: all 1s linear 0s;"><img src="http://relationshiphero.com/images/heroTeal.png" style="height: 32px; width: 32px; margin-right: 16px;"><div><div style="font-size: 12px; color: rgb(5, 26, 90); margin-bottom: 2px;">38% better value</div><div style="color: rgb(0, 112, 232); font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;">Hero - 240 minutes</div></div><div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: 8px; color: rgb(0, 112, 232);"><img src="http://relationshiphero.com/images/triangleRight.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;"></div></div></div></div><div class="rightSec"><div style="position: absolute; height: 450px; width: 341.8px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; background-image: url(&quot;/images/home/howItWorks5.jpg&quot;); background-size: cover; background-position: center top;"></div></div></div></div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'd appreciate if anyone one could have a look  at this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `display: flex;` attribute to elements that use flexbox